# Python how to display database information

Tags: python

I would like to display my database information. I tested this code but it doesn't work

```
@classmethod
def users_list(cls):
    cls.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    data = cls.cursor.fetchall()
    for row in data:
        print("Id : {}, name :{}, fistname :{}, genre :{}, address :{},
             city :{}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], 
             row[5]))
    users_list = classmethod(users_list)
```

When I execute : `users.users_list()`, I got this error

```
cls.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    AttributeError: type object 'Users' has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Do you have a solution?

Comment: What database api are you using?  What type of class is `cls`?

Comment: I'm using myqsl and pymsql as api. cls is what I see if I want to declare a static method I have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your object `users` of type `Users` has no `cursor` attribute. Based on the piece of code, there's indeed no `cursor` attribute on that object/class, so it is expected that `cls.cursor.execute(...)` throws an exception.

Comment: But when I use SELF instead of CLS, it works. I don't understand why. Like def users_list(self):

Comment: It's very likely that your `cursor` attribute is defined on the `users` object upon its initialisation, i.e., is an instance attribute. Using `cls.cursor` is only relevant if ´cursor` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute. (and by `cls.cursor`, I mean using a `classmethod` decorator, of course ;)

Comment: Cursor is a pymsql method. I don't know how can I solve that.

Comment: Either define an instance method instead of a class method, or initialize the cursor on the class itself. If you want more help, you'll need to provide more code, otherwise it will be difficult to properly get the point. Also, if an answer on SO helped you, do no forget to upvote it so other users can benefit from that answer too.